# Options for getting logs in kubernetes pods

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging, kubernetes

Have few developer logs in kubernetes pods, what is the best method to get the logs for the developers to see it.

Any specific tools that we can use?

I have the option of graylog, but not sure if that can be customized to get the developer logs into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most basic method would be to simply use `kubectl logs` command:

> Print the logs for a container in a pod or specified resource. If the
>   pod has only one container, the container name is optional.

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#logs) you can find more details regarding the command and it's flags alongside some useful examples.

Also, you may want to use:

- [Logging Using Elasticsearch and Kibana](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/logging-elasticsearch-kibana/)
- [Logging Using Stackdriver](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/logging-stackdriver/)

Both should do the trick in your case.

Please let me know if that is what you had on mind and if my answer was helpful.

Comment: Thanks. Im looking on the options to get the application logs inside the pods.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the application logs - from the development side you just need to print logs to the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` streams.

The container runtime (I guess Docker in your case) will redirect those streams
to `/var/log/containers`. 
(So if you would ssh into the Node you can run `docker logs <container-id>` and you will see all the relevant logs).

Kuberentes provides an easier way to access it by `kubectl logs <pod-name>` like @Wytrzymały_Wiktor described. 
(Notice that the logs are being rotated automatically every 10MB so the `kubectl logs` command will show the log entry from the last rotation only).

If you want to send the logs to a central logging system like (ELK, Splunk, Graylog etc') you will have to forward the logs from your cluster by running log forwarders inside your cluster.

This can be done for example by running a *daemonset* that manage a pod on each node that will access the logs path (`/var/log/containers`) by a `hostPath` volume and will forward the logs to the remote endpoint. See example [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/).