# Option for collecting logs in Kubernetes in GCP

Tags: logging, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

A semi related question: [Options for getting logs in kubernetes pods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59374234/options-for-getting-logs-in-kubernetes-pods)

I am running a tomcat application in Google Kubernetes Engine and that has output to log files like catalina.log, localhost.log and more. As these are not the usual stdout, I have several options and questions regarding the best way of pulling log files to a shared folder / volume in a Kubernetes environment.

**Option 1:**
Batch job that uses kubectl cp to move the log files to host, but I don't think this is advisable as pods die frequently and crucial log files will be lost.

**Option 2:**
I'm not sure if this is possible as I am still learning how persistent volumes work compared to docker, but is it possible to mount a PVC with the same mountPath as the tomcat/logs folder so that the logs gets written to the PVC directly?

In Docker, I used to supply the container run command with a mount-source to specify the volume used for log consolidation:

```
docker container run -d -it --rm --mount source=logs,target=/opt/tomcat/logs ....
```

I am wondering if this is possible in the Kubernetes environment, for example, in the deployment or pod manifest file:

```
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/tomcat/logs/
          name: logs
      volumes:
      - name: logs
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: logs
```

**Option 3:**
I want to avoid complicating my setup for now, but if all options are exhausted, I would be setting up ElasticSearch, Kibana and Filebeat to ship my log files.

Comment: Yes, you can mount volumes in k8s. After that you have just point the app to store logs on that volume. Additionally, there are different volume types, etc, so you can even share them between Pods. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/ explains that. Let me know if you need to know some additional info (or I misunderstood you) and I'll gladly elaborate.

Comment: Hi @Nick, my goal is to have my application write my log files into a persistent volume. In docker I can share the folder with "--mount source" , was wondering will doing the same in the mountPath manifest achieve the same thing?

Comment: I mounted a folder from my PV in /tomcat/log folder, I tried to symbolic link this to the /tomcat/logs folder where the logs are located, but it kept saying "Permission Denied". I bash/sh into the pod to attempt to manually copy it into the volume but it still had permission issues. Am I missing a step?

Comment: not sure if I uderstood correctly. So you have a PV (please add yaml to your question) , PVC (please add yaml as well)  and then you are mounting it to your Pod as /tomcat/log/ . Your tomcat is configured  writing logs into /tomcat/logs (with s) at the end, so you tried to create a symlink `ln -s /tomcat/logs /tomcat/log`  (so logs will be written to 'logs' and will land to 'log') and got an error.  After that you have tried log in to the Pod and manually copy it with the `cp -rp /tomcat/logs/ /tomcat/log/' and got an error?  Please add commands and output to the question as well.

Comment: hi @Nick Yes, that was one thing I tried, I figured out the permission issue, I noticed that the mountPath has ownership of "root" while my Dockerfile defined a user, which has less privilege than root. This caused me not being able to symlink or write to that file directly. I resolved it by changing that user to root.

I think this is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46873796/allowing-access-to-a-persistentvolumeclaim-to-non-root-user/46907452#46907452

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is actually quite simple after I figured out how everything works. Hopefully this helps someone. I went ahead for option #2.

First define a pvc for my tomcat log files:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: tomcat-logs
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

In my deployment.yaml, reference it to the PVC created:

```
...
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: opt/tomcat/logs
          name: tomcat-logs          
      volumes:
      - name: tomcat-logs
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: tomcat-logs       
...
```

As noted, the PVC is mounted as root, the container will not be able to write to it if they do not have sufficient privileges. For my case, it was my DockerFile that defined my user, and changing it to root resolves it.

Edit: If running the DockerFile as root is not viable, you can escalate the privileges in the deployment by adding:

```
...
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
....
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
```

A related question here: 
[Allowing access to a PersistentVolumeClaim to non-root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46873796/allowing-access-to-a-persistentvolumeclaim-to-non-root-user/46907452#46907452)

Comment: Glad you have found the issue. Technically, you can use initContainer to create a directory with proper permissions on that volume as well. The examplecan be found here: https://github.com/nkolchenko/technocore/blob/master/Game_of_Pods/deployment-drupal.yaml